# column is invalid in the HAVING clause because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY

Tags: sql, filter

I am trying to make my column equals the filter using having, but the problem is it gives this error message:

```
column is invalid in the HAVING clause because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY
```

and when I try to add the filter in the select and group by it says that:

```
Column names in each view or function must be unique
```

because both the column and the filter are the same:

the Column:

```
     userTable.userid
```

the Filter:

```
  user_filter.userid
```

here is my code:

```
SELECT  DISTINCT 
userId,
username,
sum(userItem)
from userTable inner join user_filter
on userTable.userName =  user_filter.userName 
group by userId,
username,
having  userTable.userId =  user_filter.userId
```

Comment: Edit your question and include the query that generates the error.

Comment: ok, I will add the query

Comment: What are you actually trying to achieve? Why are you joining by `username`, when both tables have a `userid`? And why does userfilter have a `username` anyway when the `username` is already in the `usertable`?

Comment: What DBMS are you using? MySQL, SQL Server, PostgreSQL, ...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need `Having` clause just add another filter in `Where` clause

```
SELECT userid, 
       username, 
       Sum(useritem) 
FROM   usertable 
       INNER JOIN user_filter 
               ON usertable.username = user_filter.username 
                  AND usertable.userid = user_filter.userid 
GROUP  BY userid, 
          username
```

Also `DISTINCT` is redundant because already `Group by` is used in `select`